# Angular apply different styles to different modules

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

I have an angular app and below is my routing module:

app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: WebsiteComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
        import('./website/website.module').then((m) => m.WebsiteModule)
      }
    ]
  
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./admin/admin.module').then((m) => m.AdminModule)
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

I want to apply a different style sheet (.scss) file to each route or module. I've tried adding the stylesheet to the styleUrls array of both WebsiteComponent and AdminComponent, but the styles will not affect the inner components unless I change the encapsulation on every single child component which is not feasible. So is there a different more efficient way to do that?

Comment: I suggest you create a container component(e.g.: `<app-website-container>` and `<app-admin-container>`) and disable `ViewEncapsulation.None`, all the components will go inside these containers respectively, then in your container component's style file you can write global styles for each module but important thing is to wrap all the styles in **unique parent class** (e.g.: `.webiste-container { ...all styles for website module}`)

Comment: Maybe use css-variables and set them in each module ?